# Как реализовать скалярное произведение векторов через list comprehension python

Tags: python

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
m = [n1*n2 for n1, n2 in zip(a, b)]
```

Не могу понять как докрутить сумму полученных произведений, чтобы в итоге получить одно число

Comment: m = sum([n1*n2 for n1, n2 in zip(a, b)])

Comment: `m = sum(n1*n2 for n1, n2 in zip(a, b))`

Comment: Только это будет уже генераторное выражение, если без квадратных скобок )  Но так и лучше даже, питоничнее.